# Internet connection sharing windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, firewall, share, internet

I have one windows server 2008 r2, and that server has 4 network interfaces (3 private, 1 internet connection).
I would like to share internet connection with other 3 networks.
Windows server firewall should make logs of data that is transfered.
It should not be possible to connect directly to private networks from internet.

How could I do it?

Edit:
I tried with NAT in RRAS, but it doesn't work.
Here is the configuration:
Server:
IP private:192.168.0.1
IP public: xx.xx.xx.xx

client
IP:192.168.0.2
Default gateway: 192.168.0.1

Public and private interface added in NAT section of RRAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows server 2008 provides a Routing and Remote access service, this can allow you to use NAT.

An explanation of NAT is provided [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd469848(WS.10).aspx)

*Below are taken from technet*

**Install RRAS**
Applies To: Windows Server 2008 R2

> You install RRAS by using the Add
>   Roles wizard in Server Manager.
>
> Membership in the local Administrators
>   group, or equivalent, is the minimum
>   required to complete this procedure.
>
> To install RRAS Perform one of the
>   following two steps to start the Add
>   Roles Wizard:
>
> Start Server Manager. In the main
>   window, under Roles Summary, click Add
>   roles.
>
> In the Initial Configuration Tasks
>   window that appears when you first log
>   on, under Customize This Server, click
>   Add roles.
>
> On the Before You Begin page, click
>   Next.
>
> Note This page does not appear if you
>   previously selected Skip this page by
>   default. On the Select Server Roles
>   page, select Network Policy and Access
>   Services, and then click Next twice.
>
> On the Select Role Services page,
>   select Routing and Remote Access
>   Services.
>
> On the Confirm Installation Selections
>   page, click Install.
>
> On the Installation Results page,
>   review the status, and then click
>   Close.

**Open the RRAS MMC Snap-in**
Applies To: Windows Server 2008 R2

> Use these procedures to open the
>   Routing and Remote Access MMC snap-in.
>
> Membership in the local Administrators
>   group, or equivalent, is the minimum
>   required to complete this procedure.
>
> To open the RRAS MMC snap-in by using
>   Server Manager To start Server
>   Manager, click Start, click
>   Administrative Tools, and then click
>   Server Manager.
>
> Expand Roles, expand Network Policy
>   and Access Services, and then click
>   Routing and Remote Access.

**Enable and Configure NAT**
Applies To: Windows Server 2008 R2

> Network address translation (NAT)
>   allows you to share a connection to
>   the public Internet through a single
>   interface with a single public IP
>   address. The computers on the private
>   network use private, non-routable
>   addresses. NAT maps the private
>   addresses to the public address.
>
> Membership in the local Administrators
>   group, or equivalent, is the minimum
>   required to complete this procedure.
>
> To enable network address translation
>   addressing In the RRAS MMC snap-in,
>   expand Your Server Name. If you are
>   using Server Manager, expand Routing
>   and Remote Access.
>
> Expand IPv4, right-click NAT, and then
>   click Properties.
>
> If you do not have a DHCP server on
>   the private network, then you can use
>   the RRAS server to respond to DHCP
>   address requests. To do this, on the
>   Address Assignment tab, select the
>   Automatically assign IP addresses by
>   using the DHCP allocator check box.
>
> To allocate addresses to clients on
>   the private network by acting as a
>   DHCP server, in IP address and Mask,
>   configure a subnet address from which
>   the addresses are assigned. For
>   example, if you enter 192.168.0.0 and
>   a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, then
>   the RRAS server responds to DHCP
>   requests with address assignments from
>   192.168.0.1 through 192.168.0.254.
>
> (Optional) To exclude addresses in the
>   configured network range from being
>   assigned to DHCP clients on the
>   private network, click Exclude, click
>   Add, and then configure the addresses.
>
> To add the public interface to the NAT
>   configuration, right-click NAT, and
>   then click New Interface. Select the
>   interface connected to the public
>   network, and then click OK.
>
> On the NAT tab, click Public interface
>   connected to the Internet and Enable
>   NAT on this interface, and then click
>   OK.
>
> If you want to add additional public
>   addresses assigned to this interface
>   or configure service and port mappings
>   to computers on the private network,
>   see IPv4 - NAT - Interface -
>   Properties Page.
>
> To add the private interface to the
>   NAT configuration, right-click NAT,
>   and then click New Interface. Select
>   the interface connected to the private
>   network, and then click OK.
>
> On the NAT tab, click Private
>   interface connected to private
>   network, and then click OK.